# Creating a dataframe with exist or not value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in this format (the first row is the column names)

```
dataset  stock  name1 name2 name3
dataset1 stock1 Google Yahoo GTM
dataset1 stock2 NA     Google NA
dataset1 stock3 Yahoo  Na     Google
dataset2 stock1 GTM    Yahoo  NA
dataset2 stock2 NA     NA     GTM
dataset3 stock2 GTM    Google Yahoo
```

I have another dataframe with only one columns which provides the full list of stock names:

```
name
Google
Yahoo
GTM
```

I would like to take a dataframe which shows me if every row of dataframe 1 contains (1) or not (0) the stock based on the name of the second dataframe.
Example of output (the first row is the column names)

```
dataset  stock  Google Yahoo GTM
dataset1 stock1 1       1     1
dataset1 stock2 1       0     0
dataset1 stock3 1       1     0
dataset2 stock1 0       1     1
dataset2 stock2 0       0     1
dataset3 stock2 1       1     1
```

Is there any simple way in R to make it for many values?

Comment: Try `library(reshape2) ; dcast(melt(df, 1:2, na.rm = TRUE), dataset + stock ~ value, length)`

Comment: Or with base R: `new <- cbind(dat[,1:2],apply(dat[,3:5],2,function(x) (x %in% name)*1)) ;
colnames(new) <- c(colnames(dat[1:2]),name)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thank you as I can understand length is a function of reshape2 and df is the first dataframe of my example.What I can't understand is where is the second with the names and who to use it?

Comment: `length` is a function of R. And I don't see a need in `df2` if you already have all the stock names in `df` data set values.

Comment: `dataset` and `stock` are the id columns. This is why I specified `id = 1:2` which means the first two columns. `name1`, `name2` and `name3` contains all the stock values. I don't know why can't you use this code as it works perfectly fine on your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df1, stock+dataset~value, id.var = 1:2)[, c(names(df1)[1:2], df2$name)]
#    dataset  stock Google Yahoo GTM
# 1 dataset1 stock1      1     1   1
# 2 dataset2 stock1      0     1   1
# 3 dataset1 stock2      1     0   0
# 4 dataset2 stock2      0     0   1
# 5 dataset3 stock2      1     1   1
# 6 dataset1 stock3      1     1   0
```

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="dataset  stock  name1 name2 name3
dataset1 stock1 Google Yahoo GTM
dataset1 stock2 NA     Google NA
dataset1 stock3 Yahoo  Na     Google
dataset2 stock1 GTM    Yahoo  NA
dataset2 stock2 NA     NA     GTM
dataset3 stock2 GTM    Google Yahoo")

#I have another dataframe with only one columns which provides the full list of stock names:
df2 <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header=T, text="
name
Google
Yahoo
GTM")
```

Comment: powerful! thanks! Just a question because my dataset is larger and I tried it but I receive this error `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Error in `[.data.frame`(recast(df1, stock + dataset ~ value, id.var = 1:2),  : 
  undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped ` any idea from your experience if it possible?

Comment: Sure. If you want more speed, you could also do it with the `data.table` package. The error is probably because some names in `df2$name` are not part of the transformed `df1`. Try just `recast(df1, stock+dataset~value, id.var = 1:2)`, without the subsetting.